# Implementing online learning with time series

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a classification problem with time series data.

Each example has 10 variables which are measured at irregular intervals and in the end the object is classified into 1 of the 2 possible classes (binary classification).

I have only the final class of the example to learn from during training. But when given a new example, I would like to make a prediction at each timestamp (in an online manner). So, if the new example had 25 measurements, I would like to make 25 predictions of its class; one at each timestamp.

The way I am implementing this currently is by using the min, mean and max of the measurements of its 10 variables till that point as features for classification. Is this optimal ? What would be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to make predictions at each time stamp, then this doesn't become a a time series problem (unless you plan to use the sequence of previous observations to make your next prediction, in which case you will need to train a sequence based model). Assuming you can only train a model based on the final data you observe, there can be many approaches, but I'd recommend you use Random Forest with large number of trees and 3 or 4 variables in each tree. That way even if some variables don't give you the desired input other trees can still make predictions to a fair amount of accuracy. Besides this there can be many ensemble approaches.

The way you're currently doing may be a very loose approximation and practical but doesn't make much statistical sense.

Comment: So, Timeseries is strictly *predicting the next value based on the previous values* ?

Comment: Assuming I trained the RF using the final class for each datapoint, when I wish to predict a new example's class, what features do I input to the RF for it's classification, min, mean and max of the measurements of its 10 variables till that point ?

Comment: The idea of ensemble method is where you don't use all your variables to make a single model, but make multiple models suing several small subsets of your variables... so when you a have data where some of your variables fluctuate over time due to noise, a combination of models will help you predict the value with better accuracy

Comment: Can we take this to chat ? I'd like to know your thoughts on some subtleties

Comment: While predicting at each time stamp the you can input the actual values of variables in this case... no need for min max or average

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92501/discussion-between-darshan-chaudhary-and-gaurav).